# Dialog fills screen size. I can't make it be a fixed size

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog

I'm trying to make a popup with a Dialog with a fixed height, but I can't manage to get it working.

This is my code to build the dialog:

```
Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
ScrollView scvUsersToInvite = (ScrollView) this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_users_to_invite, null);
LinearLayout usersToInvite = (LinearLayout) scvUsersToInvite.findViewById(R.id.containerUsersToInvite);
//I add several layouts to the container.
for (int i=0; i<25;i++){
    RelativeLayout usuariPerInvitar = (RelativeLayout)this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.entrada_user_invitar, usersToInvite, false);
    TextView tvNomUser = (TextView)usuariPerInvitar.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tvNomUser.setText("TextView number "+i);
    usersToInvite.addView(usuariPerInvitar);
}

dialogBuilder.setView(scvUsersToInvite);
```

This is working correctly, its filling the layout with 25 times the layout `entrada_user_invitar`

So those are the XML layouts:

`dialog_users_to_invite.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerUsersToInvite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, height is set to 50dp, but anyways nothing happens.

This is what I inflate several times:

`entrada_users_invitar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

As you can see in the picture, obviously the dialog is not 50dp height...
[image]

How should I write the XML layout to limit the height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Solved it.

I've added a parent layout on `dialog_users_to_invite.xml`

Now it is:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerUsersToInvite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Working perfectly. Everything on wrap_content except the ScrollView, which is 100dp.